# SharePoint 2013 / 2016 : "Edit" button and "Text Layout" aren't shown

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I deleted some web parts and pages from a site, but after that a couple of problems happened :

1 - The "Edit" button isn't showing anymore.

When I create a sub site it's there but not on the parent site:

Some sub site (everything's shown) :

[image]

The parent site (not showing):

[image]

2 - Text Layout isn't showing:

When I click on "Page" -> "Edit Page", "Text Layout" isn't there. But, when I create a sub site it's there.

Some sub site (everything's shown):

[image]

The parent site (not showing):

[image]

I am sorry for this unusual question, but I am still a beginner at SharePoint.

Thank you for every proposition.

Comment: what webparts and pages you deleted?

Comment: Web parts and pages I created, so basically custom lists, Tasks, Calendar, ... . I didn't delete the Web parts that are created automatically when creating a site.

Comment: Any permissions removed for this user from parent site?

Comment: I just checked, I still have all my permissions. I can create pages and edit them, it's just that the page layout option isn't there anymore and the created pages don't appear in Site pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I needed to deactivate the wiki home page feature.

Here is some other solutions for the same problem:

[I'm missing Page Layout Button On SharePoint 2010 Ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226856/im-missing-page-layout-button-on-sharepoint-2010-ribbon).